# Making 3 images sit next to eachother in bootstrap carousel and be centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, responsive

I'm trying to make a bootstrap carousel. However, I'm trying to make one of the slides consist of 3 images that sit next to each other wrapped in a div.

All the other slides in the show are centered and look nice enough, but the slide that consists of 3 img wrapped in a div just keeps floating to the left of the page even though I haven't told them to.

I will include code.

Carousel

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/jumbotron.jpg" alt="cd release promo">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/Coldclock Knockout Local 662 (10).jpg" alt="Robby and Ryan in blue">
    </div>


    <!-- Div containing 3 images --> 
    <div id="ryanSlide" class="item">
      <div id="ryanSlideContainer">
        <img src="images/Coldclock Knockout Local 662 (38).jpg" alt="Ryan 1">
        <img src="images/Coldclock Knockout Local 662 (46).jpg" alt="Ryan 2 B&W">
        <img src="images/Coldclock Knockout Local 662 (47).jpg" alt="Ryan 3">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/Coldclock Knockout Local 662 (48).jpg" alt="Crowd Shot">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>
```

CSS + bootstrap is also being used on this page

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}



/*================================================================================================

NAVIGATION  

================================================================================================*/



.active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a{
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

#navigation {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}



/*================================================================================================

JUMBOTRON

================================================================================================*/


#myCarousel img {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#ryanSlide {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#ryanSlideContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#ryanSlide img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*================================================================================================



================================================================================================*/
```

I'm not using any custom javascript.

I just cant seem to figure out how to get the one slide to center itself like the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can technically put anything in a carousel, it doesn't need to just be a single image, so you could just use bootstrap columns to do it.

For example:

```
<div id="ryanSlide" class="item">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="" class="img-responsive center-block" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="" class="img-responsive center-block" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="" class="img-responsive center-block" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did this, and it worked. Sort of. However, what happened is that the images became stretched and looked like garbage. Am I correct in thinking that I would have to add a css property restricting the max-width of the three images to the actual px size of the responsive image at its max height?

Comment: The images shouldn't stretch, bootstraps img-responsive should make any image fit without distorting it. Perhaps you have some other css rule that is affecting them? Any chance you could show the new code/put it in a bootply?